# jLabel.setOpaque(true) does not work

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jlabel

I have a jLabel which initially has setOpaque set to false by default. When I set the back ground color of the label to some color and set the setOpaque to true it does not show up the color. Why is it not displaying the color even though the setOpaque is being set to ture?

Here is what I'm trying to do.

```
JLabel key = values[i];
key.setBackground(Color.red);
key.setOpaque(true);
```

Comment: `jLabel.setOpaque(true) does not work` - Sure it does. You have a problem somewhere else in your code Post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works like a charm for me:

```
import java.awt.Color;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TestJLabel {

    protected void initUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(TestJLabel.class.getSimpleName());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JLabel key = new JLabel("Some opaque label with a yellow background.");
        key.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        key.setOpaque(true);
        frame.add(key);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TestJLabel().initUI();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Resulting in:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:-

```
JLabel key = values[i];
key.setOpaque(true);
key.setBackground(Color.red);
```

Comment: Order doesn't matter.